# typescript module as function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm writing the library in typescript and have to keep some api

```
_(1).seconds()
```

the thing is that _ is a module, and in the previous implementation was like that

```
module.exports = valueFunction;
module.exports.seconds = seconds;
```

is it possible to implement the same in typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to consider breaking it up, and have code-completion/intellisense work. There are a few options that would be closer to the original JavaScript implementation, however, getting code-completion to work can be a bit challenging.

The primary function `_` is exported, and returns an exported class called `Chained`. It's in this `class`, where the functions that hang from the return value of `_` would exist.

In the implementation file (**`sample.ts`**):

```
export class Chained {
    constructor(private val: number) {
    } 
    seconds(): number {
        return this.val / 1000;
    }
}

export function _(val: number): Chained {
    return new Chained(val);
}
```

And then in use:

```
/// <reference path="sample.ts" />

import sample = require('./sample');
// create a simple alias for the exported _ function:
import _ = sample._;

var val = _(5000).seconds();
console.log(val);
```

The output would be `5` as `seconds` divides the original number by `1000`.

If you needed the function to be available like:

```
_.seconds
```

as well as:

```
_().seconds()
```

Your options become more limited as while TypeScript supports extending a `Function` instance with properties, intellisense doesn't work:

```
// this won't work well:
export function _(val:number) : Chained {
   return new Chained(val);
}

_["seconds"] = (val:number) : number => {
   return val / 1000;
}
```